# Why is port forwarding in Mikrotik RouterOS stuck at SYN_RECV?

Tags: port-forwarding, mikrotik, routeros

I'd like to set up port forwarding of `tcp` port `8000` -> `192.168.1.16:4200` on my Mikrotik RouterOS.

I've done the following:

`/ip firewall nat add dstnat chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.1.16 to-ports=4200 protocol=tcp dst-address=<PUBLIC_IP> dst-port=8000`

When I try to use the service from the Internet then the following command just hangs:

`curl <PUBLIC_IP>:8000`

I can see the counters moving on the Mikrotik's NAT rule (via WebBox).

On the target machine, I can see the following in `netstat -an | grep 4200`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.16:4200       <REMOTE_HOST>:37720     SYN_RECV
```

I verified that I am able to connect to the machine locally via `curl 192.168.1.16:4200`.

I can't figure out what can be wrong :(

**UPDATE:** Firewall filter rules:

```
/ip firewall filter
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept established,related,untracked" connection-state=established,related,untracked
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=invalid
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept ICMP" protocol=icmp
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop all not coming from LAN" in-interface-list=!LAN
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept in ipsec policy" ipsec-policy=in,ipsec
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept out ipsec policy" ipsec-policy=out,ipsec
add action=fasttrack-connection chain=forward comment="fasttrack - except for ipsec" connection-mark=!ipsec connection-state=established,related
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept established,related, untracked" connection-state=established,related,untracked
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=invalid
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop all from WAN not DSTNATed" connection-nat-state=!dstnat connection-state=new in-interface-list=WAN
```

Comment: What other rules do you have in the firewall?

Comment: @tetech I added my firewall rules above - thanks!

Comment: Your rules look OK at first read-through.  Where does the forward rule appear in relation to the others?  Make sure `fasttrack-connection` is before it.  To test, I'd try changing `dst-address=<PUBLIC_IP>` to `in-interface-list=WAN` and start disabling other rules temporarily.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I had an `/ip firewall mangle` rule which broke some of my outgoing connections and the hosts I tried to verify my NAT connection were all involved. Sorry guys, the setup above is working indeed. Not sure, should I answer my question?